# html2canvas plugin not capturing image

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

This question has been asked before but I can't seem to get it to work. Hopefully you can see the error of my ways. The code below will capture the text and gray div but not the image.

```
<div id="snapshot" style="left: -60px; height: 1000px; width: 1000px;">
    <p>THIS IS A TEXT TEST</p>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; background: #f0f0f0">

    </div>

    <img src="http://photos.capturemyarizona.com/photos/LnnOEyWSV4fh846ohaIAQg/display.jpg" />
</div>




$("#myBtn").click ->
    html2canvas $("#snapshot"),
      background: "red"
      onrendered: (canvas) ->
        imgSrc = canvas.toDataURL()
        popup = window.open(imgSrc)
        return

    return


<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>
```

**Here's the fiddle**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XS2kA/)

Comment: Could you setup a JSFiddle to demonstrate please?

Comment: OK, I added the fiddle. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1):

OK, well I figured out what the problem is. html2canvas can't capture an image if it's not from the same origin. My images are coming from a CDN.

[html2canvas docs](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html)

Comment: Hello @isea Have you sorted out this issue ?

Comment: any workaround for this issue?
I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, this was from a couple of gigs ago, but I think we had to abandon this feature for a while